# Matlab's reshape in c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, matlab, reshape

In Matlab it is possible to 'reshape' a (N-dimensional) matrix from any dimension to any other dimension, as long as the number of elements does not change. That is:

```
A = rand(10,10);
B = reshape(A, 100, 1);
```

Matlab can do so quite efficiently, because A and B still point to the same block of 100 doubles, they are only copied if one writes to either A or B: this is called copy-on-write.

I want this reshape feature in C/C++, that is, I want to be able to do this:

```
double flat[100];
double square[10][10] = ... flat ...;
```

such that square represents the same data, but interpreters indexing in another way.

In the end, what I want is syntax sugar, to do square[i][j] instead of square[10*i+j]. So, yes, writing some class that is able to share data with different dimensions (like matlab does) overloading indexing operators may do the yob. However, I am looking for a simpler solution.

On the other hand, I am afraid that the C++ standard(s) allow for compilers to implement dimensional arrays in different ways, disallowing for what I want. For example int[10][10] may be implemented as 10 blocks on 10 doubles and one block of 10 double pointers pointing to those. Moreover, I can create such a thing myself:

```
double **blowUp(double *array, int m, int n) {
    double **r = new double[m];
    for(int i=0; i<m; ++i, array+=n) r[i] = array;
    return r;
}
```

but then the idea of syntax sugar disappears a bit, especially since I would need to clean up the wrapper array as well.

Another solution may be a templated subscript operator overload, where the the template arguments contain the first dimension of the data:

http://ideone.com/aonHN2

But as the compile errors suggest, this is not feasible without wrapping the data in a class structure. So, am I doomed to wrap data in a class and write a lot of boilerplate code if I want what I want? Please let me know what you think!

Comment: Do you know the dimensions of the reshape at compile time?

Comment: So basically, you're too lazy to write a class? :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I don't like boilerplate code. So, maybe I was too lazy too write a class which messes up my code, but I was not too lazy to construct a question on SO allowing me to find a more adequate solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I could hardcode them, since I am working with images which all have a 1600x1200 dimension, but I would find that a disappointing approach. So I guess not, what would have been your suggestion?

Comment: If you don't want to hard code the dimensions, why did you accept the answer that you did?

Comment: "messes up your code"? You wouldn't define or implement the class in the existing code, now would you? Also, when done well, it should only *benefit* your code's data management, flexibility, etc.; isn't that the very intention of object orientation in the first place? But it seems you're happy with the hacky one-off solution you got (nothing bad to Edward though, +1 for him); I'll just let time teach you its lessons.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis All I wanted to learn was whether C++ can 'reshape', as it seems like an obvious operation in such a low-level language. I like low level code, sue me. So thank you for your efforts to read my question and teach me OO, but please try to refrain from inappropriate passive aggressive notes like "you're too lazy to write a class?" and "I'll just let time teach you its lessons." If you want to convince me, use arguments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right, I accepted to soon. however, this seems to work: double (&image)[dimx][dimy][dimc] = *reinterpret_cast<double(*)[dimx][dimy][dimc]>(image); for variables dim{x,y,c}, making me believe it worked dynamically. But I (soon) found out it does not. if you have a better solution, feel free to mention it, but I think that wrapping the data in a class would be the only go. Nevertheless, I like your answer very much.

Comment: Even if you get this work with arrays like this, it will still not track its own dimensions.  Those you'll have to keep in separate variables (say, M and N).  But that's a lot of stuff to pass between functions.  Too bad there's no way to wrap multiple variables that refer to the same thing into one object...

Comment: @Peter Your sarcastic comment is not constructive. Reasons for me to pass on OO is that a wrapper will not automatically implement all the operations that are possible on a double *, hence forcing me to write a lot of boilerplate operator overloads. If you wish, you may add your OO suggestion as an answer, or workout David's answer in ideaone. Like I already stated way back in my question, I don't want to write a lot of boilerplate code just to have the operations that pointers have. I once created a wrapper class, and I hated it for needing to extend it for every simple operation I needed.

Comment: Moreover, I feel there is one more mayor argument for me not to use OO. I use C++ for small algorithms which need for-loops or priority queues, or data structures that are not very natural in Matlab. Then I mex them and use them in Matlab to run simulations and other research kind of work. This hybrid Matlab-C++ configuration allows me to work efficiently in CPU and code time. In C++ I already made the choice of not using data wrappers, like Matlab provides, and I only do so if the intended C++ code is small and self contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a simple array, this is quite easy using a `reinterpret_cast`.  Taking your example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int flat[100];
    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
        flat[i]=i;
    // now reinterpret that flat array as a 10x10 square
    int (&square)[10][10] = *reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10][10]>(flat);
    // print an arbitrary row
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        std::cout << square[5][i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

This simple program prints:

```
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
```

Comment: This is quite the contrary of what I expected, since I expected no elegant solution, but exactly what I'm looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: This requires dimensions to be known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this is to wrap the flat array in a class. You can implement use `operator[]` to return a pointer to the i<sup>th</sup> row. The implementation of this `operator[]` needs to know the shape which you wish to impose on the underlying array.